# graphicsmagick on travis build machine

Tags: node.js, travis-ci, graphicsmagick

Our unit tests require that we invoke gm (graphicsmagick) library and the package gets built by travis. I was wondering if there is any easier way to install graphicsmagick when the package starts to build:

My .travis.yml looks like:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- '0.11'
before_install:
- npm install -g grunt-cli
install:
- npm install
- grunt precheck
after_success:
- npm test
- sh ./scripts/package.sh
```

Is adding it in before_install a good solution? If yes, what would be the easiest way to install the lib?

Thanks

Comment: for now, I have added it to the before_install section like:- 

before_install:
- sudo apt-get install -y graphicsmagick libgraphicsmagick1-dev

Comment: I had a similar problem in my [node-webp](https://github.com/Intervox/node-webp) project. I needed to execute a complex webp installation script before running any tests, and to modify my environment to include certain paths to `$PATH`. I ended up with complex `Makefile` and very compact `.travis.yml`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `apt-get` to do the install of the package you need.

```
before_install
- sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
```

NOTE: if you need a new/specific version, you may need to install the PPA first.